# Form not saving

Tags: python, django

How can I save  django form without validating. I have a simple form. Like i have a dropdown option if a user select a figi it brings a different field from the model payment and if a user select bank teller it brings a different field from the model payment. So I wanna save them. But its not saving when I use form.is_valid() and it still shows me code post 200 but its not in my database and  when I remove form.is_valid(), it throws valueError:validation error. Now the imagefield doesn't save

```
class payments(models.Model):
    Amount=models.IntegerField(default=00000)
    figiID=models.CharField(default='F-00000',max_length=10,required=False)
    Bank_Teller=models.ImageField(upload_to='media/',required=False)
```

html

```
  <select id='modePayment'>
            <option value='test1'>Figi</option>
            <option value='test2'>Bank Teller</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <div class="test1 pricebox">
            <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
              <h6>Amount:{{pDetail.Amount}}</h6>
              <h6>Figi-ID{{pDetail.figiID}}</h6>
              <button style="background:#4CAF50;color:white;width:150px;height:40px;" value="submit" >Invest</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="test2 pricebox">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
              <h6>Amount:{{pDetail.Amount}}</h6>
              <h6>Bank Teller{{pDetail.Bank_Teller}}</h6>
              <button style="background:#4CAF50;color:white;width:150px;height:40px;" value="submit" >Invest</button>
            </form>
            </div>
```

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
          allDocs = Registration.objects.all()
          pDetail=payment_form()
          if request.method=='POST':
                pDetail=payment_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
                if pDetail.is_valid():
                     pDetail.save()
        context={'doc':allDocs,'pDetail':pDetail,'iDetail':investment}
         return render(request,'dashboard.html',context)
  else:
       return redirect('Tan:login')
```

Comment: can you share the code for your form?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to save the form variable **`pDetail`**.

`Views.py`

```
def dashboard(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
          allDocs = Registration.objects.all()
          pDetail=payment_form()
          if request.method=='POST':
                pDetail=payment_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
                if pDetail.is_valid():
                pDetail=pDetail.save()
                pDetail.save()                #<----- Add this
         context={'doc':allDocs,'pDetail':pDetail,'iDetail':investment}
         return render(request,'dashboard.html',context)
  else:
       return redirect('Tan:login')
```

Comment: It saves when the user's pick figi i.e it saves the text data but when the user selects 'bank teller' option which requires the an image, it doesn't save that.

Comment: @hansTheFranz yea that way too.

Comment: It saves when the user's pick figi i.e it saves the text data but when the user selects 'bank teller' option which requires the an image, it doesn't save it in the admin but I get 200 code